# Zerar valores repetidos de uma matriz

Tags: c, array, matriz

Olá, pessoal. tenho um exercício em que eu devo povoar uma matriz com números aleatórios de 0 a 9 e então devo substituir os números repetidos (exceto a primeira vez em que o número aparece) pelo número 0.
A primeira parte eu consegui fazer, mas estou com dificuldade em zerar os valores repetidos. Segue o código:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    main ()
   {
      int N, random, coluna, linha, temp, l, k;
      printf("Insira o tamanho da matriz\n");
      scanf("%d", &N);
      int matriz[N][N];
      srand(time(NULL));

    // Populei a matriz com números aleatórios  
     for (coluna = 0 ; coluna < N ; coluna++){
       for(linha = 0 ; linha < N ; linha++){
          random = rand () % 10;
          matriz[coluna][linha] = random;
          printf("%d ", matriz[coluna][linha]);
       }
     printf("\n");
     }
     printf("\n\n\n");

    // A maneira que pensei para comparar a matriz não deu muito certo...
    for (coluna = 0 ; coluna < N ; coluna++){
      for (linha = 0 ; linha < N ; linha++){
        for (k = coluna ; k < N ; k++){
          for (l = 1 ; l < N ; l++){
            if (matriz[coluna][linha] == matriz[k][l]){
                matriz[coluna][linha] = 0;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }


   for (coluna = 0 ; coluna < N ; coluna++){
      for(linha = 0 ; linha < N ; linha++){
          printf("%d ", matriz[coluna][linha]);
      }
    printf("\n");
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

O segredo é criar um vetor de inteiros com 10 posições `int cont[ 10 ]`, cada posição será um contador independente para cada número (de 0 a 9).

Segue a solução testada e comentada:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


#define MAX_COLS     (16)
#define MAX_LINS     (16)

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int i = 0;
    int cl = 0;
    int ln = 0;
    int matriz[ MAX_COLS ][ MAX_LINS ];
    int cont[ 10 ];

    /* Utiliza a data/hora atual como semente */
    srand(time(NULL));

    /* Inicializa a matriz de contagem */
    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        cont[i] = 0;

    /* Populando matriz com numeros aleatorios */
    for( cl = 0; cl < MAX_COLS; cl++ )
        for( ln = 0; ln < MAX_LINS; ln++ )
            matriz[cl][ln] = rand() % 10;

    /* Exibe matriz gerada aleatoriamente */
    for( cl = 0; cl < MAX_COLS; cl++ )
    {
        for( ln = 0; ln < MAX_LINS; ln++ )
            printf( "%d ", matriz[cl][ln] );

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    /* Conta as repeticoes de cada numero na matriz e substitui por zero */
    for( cl = 0; cl < MAX_COLS; cl++ )
        for( ln = 0; ln < MAX_LINS; ln++ )
            if( cont[ matriz[cl][ln] ]++ )
                matriz[cl][ln] = 0;

    /* Exibe matriz gerada modificada */
    for( cl = 0; cl < MAX_COLS; cl++ )
    {
        for( ln = 0; ln < MAX_LINS; ln++ )
            printf( "%d ", matriz[cl][ln] );

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Saída:

```
8 4 2 3 0 6 2 0 7 0 7 9 4 7 9 2
6 7 2 6 3 4 5 2 2 5 7 2 1 8 9 8
3 5 6 7 3 4 0 6 7 7 4 1 7 6 5 4
6 7 2 3 1 8 9 1 7 6 5 9 4 9 0 9
9 9 0 5 1 3 4 2 2 5 4 7 8 2 6 1
4 1 5 5 2 7 0 2 4 4 6 8 4 3 2 3
8 1 6 1 8 0 1 1 3 7 1 5 5 7 6 9
4 2 4 5 6 5 2 7 8 8 7 8 3 4 2 4
7 8 1 8 4 4 8 1 9 4 2 7 7 2 2 0
0 3 8 0 1 6 8 2 8 4 0 9 5 5 3 0
9 0 1 6 9 3 0 2 1 7 2 9 4 8 5 6
3 0 2 9 4 9 4 4 2 9 0 1 5 3 9 8
2 3 3 6 5 8 3 3 4 2 7 3 6 2 1 3
9 1 9 6 9 3 0 2 4 6 8 4 9 2 7 5
9 1 4 4 1 8 1 5 3 7 8 8 8 8 6 7
8 9 7 8 4 3 2 1 4 7 2 7 5 0 4 3

8 4 2 3 0 6 0 0 7 0 0 9 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Espero que seja util!

Comment: Esse código também será mais rápido que quatro `for` um dentro do outro.

Comment: Oi! Entendi boa parte do código, exceto as linhas 40-44, que é a parte que troca o número por 0. Se o contador na posição [cl][ln] da matriz aumentar, a matriz [cl][ln] vira 0... Mas por que o contador aumenta?

Comment: @Dervel 1) A condição do `if` é `se o contador for diferente de zero`; 2) O contador só será incrementado após a avaliação do `if`.

Comment: @Dervel Eis um código equivalente: `if( ++cont[ matriz[cl][ln] ] > 1 ) matriz[cl][ln] = 0;`

Comment: @Lacobus Acho que agora eu entendi. Se o contador for maior que 1, ele zera a matriz. É isso?

Comment: Exatamente @Dervel! fique atento ao  operador de incremento `++`, quando ele é usando antes da variável (ex.: `++i;`), o incremento acontece antes da avaliação da expressão (pre-incremento), quando ele é usado depois da variável (ex.: `i++;`), o incremento acontece depois da avaliação da expressão (pós-incremento).

Comment: @Dervel "A simplicidade é o último grau de sofisticação." _Leonado da Vinci_

Comment: @Lacobus Estou tentando fazer em uma forma mais simplificada (ou, feia, como preferir hehe) ainda. Eu posso incrementar o cont antes do if? Tentei dessa forma, mas não foi...    ` for( cl = 0; cl < MAX_COLS; cl++ )
        for( ln = 0; ln < MAX_LINS; ln++ )
         cont[matriz[cl][ln]]++;
   if(cont[matriz[cl][ln]] > 1 ){
    matriz[cl][ln] = 0;
   }`

Comment: @Dervel Faltaram as chaves: `for( cl = 0; cl < MAX_COLS; cl++ ) { for( ln = 0; ln < MAX_LINS; ln++ ) { cont[ matriz[cl][ln] ]++; if( cont[ matriz[cl][ln] ] > 1 ) { matriz[cl][ln] = 0; } } }`